# Why can C++ use the derived struct to instantiate its parent template struct and the parent template can call functions of the child struct?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, static

I have some questions about template struct.

1. Why does C++ allow the derived struct to instantiate its parent template struct?
2. Why can the struct `Base` call the **static** function `call()` by using the operator `::`? (Not **static** is illegal)
3. `TYPENAME(PType)` doesn't replace the `PType` with `D`, why?

Please see the code below. Thank you!

```
// Base.h

#pragma once
#include<iostream>

#define TYPENAME(var) #var

template<typename PType>
struct Base
{
public:
    inline void Init() {
        std::cout <<TYPENAME(PType)<<"\tBase::Init() called" << std::endl;
        PType::call();
    }
};

struct D :public Base<D> {

public:
    inline static void call() {
        std::cout <<TYPENAME(D)<<"\tD:call() called" << std::endl;
    }
};

//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "Base.h"

int main() {
    D d;
    d.Init();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A derived type passing itself to a base class template has a name. Look at [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does C++ allow the derived struct to instantiate its parent template struct?

Why not? You can instantiate `Base<some_type>` by supplying `some_type`. Nowhere does it say that a class like `D` cannot use itself as `some_type`.

> Why can the struct Base call the static function call() by using the operator ::? (Not static is illegal)

Anyone can call a static function by using `type::call()`. Not limited to (or special for) base classes. If you know the type and the member name, you can call it.

> TYPENAME(PType) doesn't replace the PType with D, why?

`TYPENAME` is a macro. Macros are handled by the preprocessor, before the compiler sees the code.

The preprocessor only sees `TYPENAME(PType)` and so inserts `PType` as a text.